# How do you initialize an more-dimensional array in x86 assembly?

Tags: arrays, assembly, multidimensional-array, x86, x86-64

I would like to create an array in an x86 assembly file and fill it with values.

The array should look somewhat like this
[5, 4, 3]
[2, 1, 0]

I want to create it in the .data section.

This is the code I wrote so far but it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone spot the mistake or help me otherwise?

```
section .data
    myArray db 5, 4, 3
            db 2, 1, 0
```

Comment: A C multi-dimensional array is still stored in contiguous memory, same as a 1D array, it's just syntactic sugar for indexing it.  Since you have to do index calculations manually in assembly anyway, it doesn't matter whether you consider it a 2D array or 2D indexing into a 1D array.  Your `.data` section is correct.  If you have code that loads from it incorrectly, that's where the problem is; this isn't a [mcve].  Or convincing your debugger to display it in a 2D format?

Comment: *but it doesn't seem to work* is not an appropriate problem description. Show what you are trying to do with your array and describe *what* doesn't work